# Twin Prime Number in C loop is only giving first value

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, primes

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
  int num1, num2, num3, fac1 = 0, fac2 = 0, fac3 = 0, i;
  clrscr();
  for (num1 = 5; num1 < 100; num1 = num1 + 1) {
    for (i = 1; i <= num1; i++) {
      if (num1 % i == 0) {
        fac1 = fac1 + 1;
      }
    }
    num2 = num1 - 2;
    for (i = 1; i <= num2; i++) {
      if (num2 % i == 0) {
        fac2 = fac2 + 1;
      }
    }
    num3 = num1 + 2;
    for (i = 1; i <= num3; i++) {
      if (num3 % i == 0) {
        fac3 = fac3 + 1;
      }
    }

    if (fac1 <= 2 && fac2 <= 2) {
      printf("%d and %d are twin prime numbers\n", num1, num2);
    }
    if (fac1 <= 2 && fac3 <= 2) {
      printf("%d and %d are twin prime numbers\n", num1, num3);
    }
  }
  getch();
}
```

The goal is to print twin prime numbers up to a certain number in this case 100 but as I start from 5 I only get this output 
5 and 3 are twin prime numbers
5 and 7 are twin  prime numbers

Comment: You need to reset your counters, `fac1`, `fac2`, `fac3`, for each iteration (inside the outer loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration of your num1 loop you should clear fac1..3. Once `fac1` reaches 2 the if clauses are never met again.

Your code shows also much room for optimization: All even numbers are no candidates for a hit. If you run the code with num1=5 you test both num1-2 and num1+2. Later with num1=7 you test again the pair 5 - 7.

Here my code with a seperate prime-tester:

```
#include <stdio.h>

bool IsPrime(int num)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 3; i < num; i+=2) 
     if (num % i == 0) return false;
  return true;
}

void main() 
{
   int num;
   clrscr();
   for (num = 3; num < 100; num += 2) 
   {
      if (IsPrime(num) && IsPrime(num+2))
         printf("%d and %d are twin prime numbers\n", num, num+2);
   }
   getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is giving only two results because your code for finding twin primes is not being repeated for other numbers. You will have to repeat the procedure for successive numbers.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int isPrime(int n);

void main() {

  int num;
  clrscr();
    for(num = 5; num < 100; num = num+1)
    {
        if(isPrime(num) && isPrime(num + 2))
        {            
            printf("%d and %d are twin prime numbers\n", num, num+2);
            num= num + 2; 
        }                
    }    
   getch();
}

int isPrime(int n)
{
    if(n == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
        {
            // number is not prime
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // number is prime
    return 1;
}
```